# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset of jwt

Tags: php, json-rpc

I have the following response from jsonRPC endpoint:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "jwt": "EXAMPLE"
    }
}
```

When I log $response->getRpcResult() I get

```
{
        "jwt": "EXAMPLE"
    }
```

When I try taking the value of jwt using
$token = $response->getRpcResult()["jwt"]

> I get phP message: PHP Warning: Illegal string offset of jwt

Any help is appreciated, I'm a beginner in PHP.

Comment: It should work (tested with your endpoint output and worked for me). Maybe the response isn't really that? Can you please share more of your code or the endpoint itself to verify the response?

Comment: You should examine the result of `$response->getRpcResult()` - the error message is telling you there's no key with a value of `jwt` in the result array.

Comment: I'll check again. I'll be right asap

Comment: Looks like you got JSON, and still need to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

No need for getRpcResult().
Just this should do:

```
$token = $response['jwt'];
dump($token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using:

```
$token = json_decode(json_encode($response->getRpcResult()), true)["jwt"];
```

I have no idea why I need to decode it again.